# Why is <h2> acceptable as the first heading of an <article>?

Tags: html

Consider this example from [the nav element spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-nav-element):

```
<body>
  <h1>The Wiki Center Of Exampland</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/events">Current Events</a></li>
      ...more...
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2>Demos in Exampland</h2>
      <p>Written by A. N. Other.</p>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#public">Public demonstrations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#destroy">Demolitions</a></li>
        ...more...
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <section id="public">
        <h2>Public demonstrations</h2>
        <p>...more...</p>
      </section>
      <section id="destroy">
        <h2>Demolitions</h2>
        <p>...more...</p>
      </section>
      ...more...
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p><a href="?edit">Edit</a> | <a href="?delete">Delete</a> | <a href="?Rename">Rename</a></p>
    </footer>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <p><small>© copyright 1998 Exampland Emperor</small></p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Given that an `<article>` represents a self-contained piece of content, I don't understand why `<h2>Demos in Exampland</h2>` is an `<h2>` instead of an `<h1>`. 
 That seems to couple the self-contained content to the context in which it happens to be appearing.

If we merely want to style that header smaller than the main page header `<h1>The Wiki Center Of Exampland</h1>`, wouldn't it be better to target it with CSS only?

More generally, it seems that header numbering should reset whenever we enter a new sectioning content context.

Does the spec address these points specifically anywhere?

Comment: ["There is no document outline algorithm"](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html), which is what you're essentially referring to with wanting `<h1>`s within `<article>`.

Comment: @zzzzBov, Thanks, that was an interesting read.  I'm still not entirely clear on the conclusion: Is using multiple `<h1>` for sectioned content currently _wrong_ according to the spec?

Comment: @Jonah - No, but all h1 elements are treated as being at the same level regardless of how deep inside sectioned content they are. If you want to indicate the heading of a subsection of a section headed by an `<h1>` use an `<h2>`. Similarly, for a sub-sub-section use an `<h3>`. And so on.

Comment: @Alohci apparently the validator currently gives a warning when you have multiple h1

Comment: @Jonah - Warnings are not errors. They're flags to indicate places where you should manually check to make sure you're doing it right. This makes sense given that it's a widely used practice to have a single top-level heading for your page. But it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are generally correct, but there is no automation for which HTML tag can follow which particular other one, or how hierarchy can be organized. That's all up to the programmer - mistakes can be made... The only option is to check for validity, and even the hierarchy of header tags isn't a must concerning HTML validity.